# Capitalization and Usage for "Fundamental Theorem of the Calculus" in tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis, grammar

Is there a standard way on M.SE to refer to the Fundamental Theorem of the Calculus in tag wikis? What I've just written is what I was taught, but I recognize there are many other ways. Interestingly, the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) uses multiple ways inside, including "fundamental theorem of calculus" and "Fundamental Theorem of Calculus". It's not clear whether including "the" in the theorem's title is standard or not.

It comes down to two questions:

1. Should the theorem's title be capitalized?
2. Should the word "the" be included in the theorem's title?

Comment: I've never seen it with "Fundamental Theorem of ***the*** Calculus", but that may be because I grew up in a culture which abbreviates mathematics by using "math," where it is common elsewhere to refer to "maths", perhaps even "the maths".  So I would expect some variation.  I typically capitalize the significant terms of titles.  But, again, I can't say "my way" is correct.

Comment: What you mean by the phrase *in tags* in the title of your question. I do not see [tags](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tagging/info) being mentioned anywhere in the body of the question.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Question edited.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this still does not clarify they question. Do you perhaps means *posts* rather than *tags*? Is this meant as a proposal to create (fundamental-theorem-of-calculus) tag?

Comment: Or it this perhaps related to [the tag-info for (calculus) tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/calculus/info) which you [recently edited](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/26814/revisions)?

Comment: Yes, tag wikis. I can edit again for that.

Comment: I definitely do NOT propose to add a special tag just for the FTC, as important as that theorem is.

Comment: Anyway, instead of answering in a big field, I'll just chime in and say, "yes, (t) F T of C"  should be capitalized, to help set it apart as a theorem, and also, I have to vote against the inclusion of the term "the" between "Theorem of" and "Calculus".

Comment: @amWhy: Great! Thanks for your input!